# Azure webapp up command specify sku for App Service to run on

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

When I run the following command, it **always** overrides the current setting for my App Service plan (called MyPlan, which I want to be B1), switching it to F1 (Free plan). Even if I specify the sku of the app service, it will somehow overwrite the plan and change it back to F1. I want to make changes to my webapp but keep the plan at B1, and stay at B1. How can I run this `webapp up` command and maintain my App Service Plan's current sku?

`az webapp up --location centralus --name mywebapp --resource-group MyRG --plan MyPlan --sku B1 --html`

Answer (score 1):

We have reproduced the below cmdlet in our environment and successfully got the output with the same **sku-B1** plan without any change in the **sku**:

```
az webapp up --location centralus --name ***test --resource-group ****** --plan ***** --sku B1 --html
```

[image]

The below is the screenshot after executing the command:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure to give the correct `AppServiceName`  before running the above command.

Comment: Yes I believe that somehow, the .azure/config file was affecting the sku. I also used the ```--dryrun``` flag and saw the output before running the whole command. As long as the dryrun showed the sku as "B1" then it worked fine.